# Workflow email action on Object

Tags: email, workflow

I have a custom object called Employee__c which has a Send_Email__c checkbox. On toggling the checkbox to true, I wanted to send email to that particular employee with a particular email template using a Workflow rule action.

Can this requirement be achieved? If so, how?

Comment: You could achieve this using Process Builder, using ISCHANGED on the `Send_Email__c` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your process builder criteria like this:

[image]

Where the field is `Send_Email__c`

Additionally, check your `Send_Email__c` is `Equal` to `True`

Comment: Shouldn't you also check that it changes *to* true?

Comment: @AdrianLarson good point. Thou I usual just trigger on toggle myself...